# Open multiple websites in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, netbeans

[Open other website without closing the previous one]

I am working on two ASP.NET websites in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Is there any option to open more than  one websites in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate?

This feature is offered in NetBeans while I was working with PHP projects.

Comment: Do you mean launch more than one project within a solution at a time?  Or do you mean two separate solutions?

Comment: You can add additional *projects* to an existing *solution*.

Comment: Open other website without closing the previous one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, you can add multiple websites to the same solution. But if you want to add multiple startup websites. Read here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx

Comment: [Open other website without closing the previous one]

Comment: Yes, this link tells you how to do it without having to close the previous websites.

Comment: Can't figure out how to do in VS 2013 :(

Comment: Try this: 
Open the Solution Property Pages dialog box.
Select Startup Project set under Common Properties.
In the pane on the right, select Multiple Startup Project.
In the Action field for each project, select a start option:
Start   Run the project when you start the debugger
Start without debugging   Run the project when you start the debugger, but do not debug this project.
None   Do not start this project when you run the debugger.

Comment: Can't find Common Properties
There are Web Site Preperties

Comment: This is in the solution property not the website property. If you don't have a solution as part of your website, I suggest you add a solution for it, and then you can access common properties

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46036/discussion-between-kant-and-user3110335)